# Replacing process with child process

Tags: winapi

I am trying to replace a parent process with a child process while maintaining the same PID.

How can I do that in windows?

Ps: I am trying to make a "proxy" program that runs before another program X that yet another program Y calls. Y should see a child with same PID.

Comment: You can't. Without some extreme hackery, that is - i.e. loading the process yourself in the context of the original one.

Comment: why the downvote? something wrong with the question?

Comment: Restored ;) `/* Comments must be at least 15 characters in length. */`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in Windows. In Linux, the [exec()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html) system call does exactly what you're looking for, but on Windows, there's no such equivalent.